# Iterating through Firebase Data Android with Unique Keys

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Using Firebase with a simple data structure, I am missing how to read my data containing unique keys. Keys are generated using:

`String key = myRef.child("users").push().getKey();`

and adding my data works fine with:

```
myRef.child("users").child(userID).child("favorites").child(key).setValue(newSite);
```

My data is structured simply:

```
Users
 - UserID
  - Favorites
   - KEY : VALUE
```

I am able to see my data like so showData(dataSnapshot):

```
for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
   String data = ds.child(userID).child("favorites").getValue().toString();
   Log.v("DATA", "DATA: " + data);
}
```

data returns: `{-L-DpQQCX8GYKPWclOX4=test}` for example. Are we then to iterate over the object returned? or am i doing this wrong with Firebase and should be getting each value somehow? If there is documentation on this, please share the link. I am not finding it for the random key.

EDIT:::

My listener is:

```
 myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            showData(dataSnapshot);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            // Failed to read value
            Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
        }
    });
```

I was able to see the key data by parsing the object:

```
JSONObject json = null;
            try {
                json = new JSONObject(data);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            for(Iterator<String> iter = json.keys();iter.hasNext();) {
                String key = iter.next();
                Log.e("KEY",key);
                array.add(key);
            }
```

Comment: Please update your question to also include the code that attaches a listener, since that determines the type of snapshot you get.

Answer (score 1):

To get data from a Firebase database you don't need to use `JSONObject`. You can simply attach a listener and iterate over the `dataSnapshot` object using `getChildren()` like this:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference favoritesRef = rootRef.child("users").child(userID).child("favorites");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String key = ds.getKey();
            String value = ds.getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", key + value);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
    }
};
favoritesRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Using this code, you can get all keys and values from `favorites` location.